# Android: Is it possible to call a method directly from setOnClickListener()?

Tags: java, android, methods, onclicklistener

I am dynamically creating some buttons and ideally would like to be able to have a method run if the button is pressed.

Is something like the following even possible?

```
private void someMethod(int ID){
 //on button pressed do something with the ID
}

private void otherMethod(){

  for( Program element : someList)
  {
    addButton.setOnClickListener(someMethod(element.getID));
  }
}
```

Obviously thats just a mock up of some code to illustrate my question. I know you can instantiate a new class so it seems like you should be able to call a method although so far I just keep getting errors with my attempts.

I have had a look around the web but can't find anything to answer this, so thought I would ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setOnClickListener` defines what will happen when the button is clicked. Setting it multiple times for the same button is meaningless; the last one you set will be the active one.

To call a method **within** a listener, declare an anonymous class override:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           someMethod(...);
        }
});
```

If you're trying to set up multiple buttons with  similar functionality, you need to loop through the *buttons* (in a list, say), and set each of their `OnClickListener`s. To achieve a differing variable per button, you could use the `View`'s [tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29):

```
for (Button b : buttons) {
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             someMethod(v.getTag());
        }
    });
}
```

Now you can simply set the `Button`'s `tag` property in the XML (or [manually](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)) to whatever you wish and it will get passed into the listener (and thus the method).

Comment: Sorry if this is a daft question but why is the loop inside it?

Comment: I wasn't sure what you're going after. I edited my answer in case you're trying to do multiple buttons that all call `someMethod` with different parameters.